# React Native 0.62.2 Appearance return wrong color scheme

Tags: react-native

On iOS simulator (13.3) and Android 10

I have an issue with `Appearance` and `useColorScheme` when I set up dark mode it's still returned "light".

```
import { useColorScheme, Appearance } from 'react-native';

const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
console.log(colorScheme, Appearance.getColorScheme()) // "light", "light"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Any article to change theme in this way! It's new?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the problem.

Problem related to this pull request https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f7b90336be25b78935549aa140131d4d6d133f7b - when debugger is active you will always get "light" theme. Just close debugger and everything will be good.

Comment: Make sure to check [Emad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63554720/8211365) first.

Answer (score 18):

add

```
"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
```

to app.json

Comment: For me it was this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68249064/5115

Answer (score 12):

Also make sure you do **not** have `UIUserInterfaceStyle` set in your `Info.plist`. I had it set to 'light' so `Appearance.getColorScheme()` was always returning 'light'.

Answer (score 1):

In your app in ios folder => your-project-name => Info.plist add the unspecified value instead of Light or Dark.

```
        <dict>
            <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
            <string>unspecified</string>
        </dict>
```