# Dark Mode: useColorScheme() always returns light on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, darkmode

I am trying to get Dark Mode to work and it doesn't work on Android. It always returns "light". On iOS it works fine.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const theme = useColorScheme();
  alert("your color scheme is: " + theme); // always returns "light" on Android
  return null;
}
```

I am using Expo SDK 42.

I put `"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"` in my `app.json` but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native 0.62.2 Appearance return wrong color scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124229/react-native-0-62-2-appearance-return-wrong-color-scheme)

Comment: no it doesn't. I don't have the debugger enabled. And it happens on several devices in Expo and when build the app for Android (APK)

Answer (score 31):

I figured it out. It was not enough to just put `"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"` in app.json root, I had to define it for iOS and Android individually too:

**app.json:**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "ios": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    },
    "android": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, that's hillarious. It definitely should be added to the documentation or just fixed to fallback to top-level value. Thanks!

Comment: It is important to note that remote debugging should be turned off, as when on it will always return "light". To turn on or off remote debugging type "m" on CLI to open the menu on your device and then turn on/off remote debugging. Happy hacking ;)

Answer (score 0):

worked for me

```
{
  expo {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "ios": {
     "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    },
    "android": {
     "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; the solution is to set these properties in the **app.json** file manually for both iOS and android.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "ios": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    },
    "android": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    }
  }
}
```